# windows service timer

Tags: c#

I have one windows service which is running in every one min. But I want to run that windows service in every 30 sec. So what changes I need to do? I have timer interval as 60,000 for 1 min.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried changing the timer interval for example to 30000 ms (30 s)?